# Processing CSV through php function

Tags: php, arrays, function, csv

I made a PHP function that works with an API to show me the dollar balance of an account. This function is called: `get_balance`

```
function get_balance($account){

$url = 'http://mycompaniesurl.com/' . $account;           // url of website         
global $response;
$ch = curl_init();                                          
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                        
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);              
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);                        
$response = curl_exec($ch);                                 
curl_close($ch);
}
```

The function get_balance returns the output in the variable $response

I'm certain that the function works, so I have no questions on that part. However, I'm trying to process accountnumbers written down in a CSV file. I call the CSV file with the following code:

```
$file = new SplFileObject("test.csv");
$file->setFlags(SplFileObject::READ_CSV);
$data = call_user_func_array('array_merge', iterator_to_array($file));

$data = array_combine(range(1, count($data)), $data);
extract($data, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'variable');
```

I'm testing my code with a csv file called test.csv, containing 4 addresses (first one has a balance of 0, other 3 have a balance of >0).

With the following code I get the balance with the accountnumber printed to my screen:

```
get_balance($data[2]);
if ($response > 0){ 
    echo $response,"---------------",$data[2];  
}
```

Because `$data[1]` has a balance of 0, nothing is printed. `$data[2]`,`$data[3]` and `$data[4]` have a balance of more than 0, so they do return the balance together with the accountnumber.

Now what my question is; is there a way to 'automatically' do this? Something like

```
get_balance($data[]);
```

seems to not work. The CSV that this php file has to process is about ~1000 accountnumber and may have more in the future, so typing a `get_balance($data[1])` up to `get_balance($data[999])` will be a time consuming business.

Is there a (simple) way to apply the function to ALL the `$data[]` ?

Comment: You are processing it... so? Where's the actual question?

Comment: +0.5 for pointing me to `SqlFileObject::READ_CSV`, hadn't stumbled across that before.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: Edited the post now, I posted the question before finishing it. Sorry for that..

Comment: I'm surprised you're using fancy stuff like `iterator_to_array` but have no idea how to automate this simple task, even if just with a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is, called [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/array_map):

```
$balanced_data = array_map("get_balance", $data);
```

This will leave `$balanced_data` empty, because at the moment `get_balance` has no return, but uses a global variable. Change it to something like this

```
function get_balance($account){
    $url = 'http://mycompaniesurl.com/' . $account;           // url of website
    $ch = curl_init();                                          
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);                        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);              
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 3);                        
    $response = curl_exec($ch);                                 
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
```

---

If you don't want to or can't change `get_balance`, you will need a workaround like this

```
$max = count($data);
for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $response = 0; // reset to make sure we get a new value
    get_balance($data[$i]);
    $balanced_data[$i] = $response;
}
```

Comment: I did this, and then use print_r($balanced_data);

However that gives the following output:
Array ( [1] => [2] => [3] => [4] => )

It does not give the response from the function

Comment: Please post the full function in the question

Comment: added it to my original post

Comment: @Bob please see my update. I would really suggest the first solution, since global variables as return values are usually bad practice

Comment: Thank you so much, the first solution worked perfectly :) I did not know global variables had this side-effect.